# Postgres on delete cascade

Tags: sql, postgresql, cascade

I'm not sure, if the deletion of rows of my psql relation with a `REFERENCE ... ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint worked properly.

I created a relation as following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE formula (
  id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
  mass numeric(13,8) NOT NULL CHECK (mass > 0),
  parent bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES id ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

After importing some data, I wanted to delete all rows, with masses >= 1000.0 matching the condition id = parent. I executed following query, to get the (minimum) amount of deleted rows:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM formula WHERE mass >= 1000.0 AND id = parent;

    count   
  ----------
   25800000
```

Now I know, that 25800000 rows match the conditions. Because of the `REFERENCE ... ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint, I expected to delete more than 25800000 rows. I know, that there are rows, which not match the condition id = parent, but should be deleted anyways, because the already mentioned constraint.

I executed the following query, to delete the rows.

```sql
DELETE FROM formula WHERE mass >= 1000.0 AND id = parent;

  DELETE 25800000
```

Now I wonder, why the delete count is also 25800000 rows. The number of deleted rows should be higher. Or does `DELETE` only count the deleted rows without the cascade?

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit (Solution)

I checked the constraints of my relation again using `\d+ formula`.
While my old relation looks like this:

```sql
[...]
Indexes:
    "pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

Foreign-key constraints:
    "parent_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES formula(id) ON DELETE CASCADE

Referenced by:
    TABLE "formula" CONSTRAINT "parent_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES formula(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

My new relation looks like this:

```sql
[...]
Indexes:
    "formula_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

So... If the foreign key declaration is not there, of course this can't work properly.

Thanks for your help. Without that, I would not have checked the constraints again.

Comment: Think about the condition `WHERE ... id = parent`. What values for `id` and `parent` do you think that might cascade to?

Comment: `DELETE` will always only report the number of delete rows of the table mentioned in the DELETE statement. "cascaded" deletes will never be included.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Interesting. I didn't know that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is good to know (And could be added to the postgres docs).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Checked the constraints again and found the original source of the problem.